# NullPointerException on some phones, not others (same API level)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-handler

I have an Android app that is getting a NullPointerException on some phones (all 2.3.x) but not on my phone (also 2.3.x) or on any of the simulators.

The particular exception doesn't seem to give any indication that it is occurring within my code, so I assume I am making a call that some version of the same API thing is incorrect? I'm not sure what to make of it.

Here is the error log from logcat:

```
01-23 14:25:33.614: D/AndroidRuntime(25648): Shutting down VM
01-23 14:25:33.614: W/dalvikvm(25648): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception          (group=0x4001d648)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at   android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7479)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3932)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1784)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1157)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2228)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1759)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2352)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1992)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
01-23 14:25:33.634: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the stack trace from the debugger:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1994  
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 150 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4293    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 849  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 607 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

The error happens immediately when the activity starts, and although none of the debugging info indicates anywhere in my code, I am guessing something in `onCreate()` would lead to it, so here's the `onCreate()` for the activity in question:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    int pid = getIntent().getIntExtra("pid", -1);
    mCurrSlide = null;
    myPresentation = thingListVideos.getVideoByPID(pid);

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(Player.this, "...",
            "downloading stuff", true, true);
    video_handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Log.v(TAG, "Dismissed Dialog");
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            prepareVideoView(videoView);
            videoView.requestFocus();
        }
    };

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mCurrSlideThread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    getTiming();
                    videoView.postDelayed(mCurrSlideThread, 1000);
                }
            };
            sView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutS);
            prepare(slideView);
            video_handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).start();

}
```

I know that it isn't actually doing any of the work that it would be doing inside the new thread it creates at the end, as the progress dialogue never shows up and it would log the work it does if it did it (and indeed it does when I run it on my phone or a simulator).

I am somewhat new to android and I have no idea what could be causing this, or why it would occur on some devices and not others even when they should have identical versions of the android API. If anyone has seen something like this before or has any idea what could be causing it, some pointers as to where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: please check ..you gave proper permission in Android Manifestfile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are purposely setting up a race condition, you must be prepared for your control, etc. to not exist yet.  Timing is everything, and that's why it "works on my machine".

You **should not start threads** in `onCreate` since you are racing with the activiy start up sequence.  Using an `AsyncTask` would be a better way to go; the system manages the threading for you!

The `onPause` and `onResume` methods are where you should be doing thread management.  These are the lifecycle events that occur when your activity is being obscured and un-obscured.  For non-UI processing you could use `onStart` and `onStop` so you can get more processing in, but not for UI-related stuff.

The "check for `null`" advice still applies.

Comment: hmm, ok thanks. I didn't think about it being a concurrency problem, which pretty dumb of me. What do you mean by "check for null" advice though?

Comment: Looks like this didn't work, although it helped me solve another problem. I think the problem is occurring before the thread is created (now an asynctask), possible in the parent activity.